# Very strange behavior bootstrap modal backdrop

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple modal like this one:

```
<div id="editbox-settings" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editbox-settings" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="aligncenter textbold">
                    <h3>Settings</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified tabs-holder" style="white-space:nowrap">
                    <li><a id="tab-1" class="btn btn-default ctrl-tabs" href="#fakelink">Image</a></li>
                    <li><a id="tab-2" class="btn btn-default ctrl-tabs" href="#fakelink">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-contents mt30">
                    <div id="tab-1" class="clearfix content-box" style="display: none;">
                        //content tab 1
                    </div>
                    <div id="tab-2" class="clearfix content-box" style="display: none;">
                        //content tab 2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-default close-modal">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I open this modal something strange happen, the backdrop area will be added inside the modal as you can see here below:

```
 <div id="editbox-settings" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editbox-settings" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; padding-right: 0px;">
//backdrop added here       
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in" ></div>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <div class="aligncenter textbold">
                        <h3>Settings</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified tabs-holder" style="white-space:nowrap">
                        <li><a id="tab-1" class="btn btn-default ctrl-tabs" href="#fakelink">Image</a></li>
                        <li><a id="tab-2" class="btn btn-default ctrl-tabs" href="#fakelink">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-contents mt30">
                        <div id="tab-1" class="clearfix content-box" style="display: none;">
                            //content tab 1
                        </div>
                        <div id="tab-2" class="clearfix content-box" style="display: none;">
                            //content tab 2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-block btn-default close-modal">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have to make this modal draggable, but if I do that it will of course drag the backdrop too.

Someone knows why the backdrop is added inside the modal dialog?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd love to help, but I don't have enough information. No idea what you're using to make it draggable. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, thanks for your reply. The mention to the draggable feature is just informative. This is not my problem. The problem I would like to solve is to avoid that the `modal-backdrop` div will be added inside the modal dialog. I am currently using version 3.5. I have never had  such a issue before. The backdrop should normally be added to the body.

Comment: Also making a fiddle with the code to verify the issue will not help. If set only the modal in a fiddle works just fine. But in my contest will not.

Comment: I asked for *mcve* because this is not default behavior of Bootstrap modal. If you're able to reproduce it, I (think and hope I) am able to find out why it's appended inside the modal and not to the `<body>` element, as it should be. Usually, when one debugs, they should first try to fix the cause. If that's not possible, we'll look into fixing/hiding the effect.

Comment: I am developing a CMS where will be possible to build the pages by dragging and drop the `html` blocks on the page. Additionally all of this is in the Codeigniter framework. I hope you will understand that it is not possible for me to reproduce that in a fiddle. If it was possible I have it done. Maybe you could helpe with some advise on how I could debug this and where to look for. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to debug the Bootstrap opening event with a simple but quite effective `console.log(this,arguments)`. In `arguments` you need to find the cause. Comparing it with `arguments` of opening a modal without the effect will prove useful at excluding causes. If that doesn't get you anywhere, you'll need to look at differences in markup between the two. That's everything there is to it, really, but experience in doing it can make one become very efficient and fast.